# Rails 4 - two similar models - Best practice to implement them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

He there,

I'm wondering how i could implement two models which are 70% similar, but with some different columns.

In the app, i can create a contract which has many deadlines. I have several types of contracts, and based on these types, my deadline model should be a little bit different.

For instance, if the contract type is 'financial', its deadlines will be composed of a "date", an "amount", and a "status"; whereas if the contract type is "General", its deadlines will be composed of a "date", a "received status" and a "status".

Both models share "date" and "status" columns. I have few other types of contract.

Should i create a single Model deadline with all the columns?
Should i create one Model DeadlineFinancial, DeadlineGeneral, ... for each of the contract types?
Another solution?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to look into [`Single Table Inheritance`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html). I can write about it if you want, although it won't be a direct answer

Comment: With STI the ease to get has_many :contracts, and then scope of the subtypes of contracts - as well as putting the shared logic in the base class is great.. see https://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/

Comment: Many thanks i'm going to take a look at that :)

Comment: Update : after having read this document, i'm still not comfortable about the fact that there will be empty fields depending on which type of Deadline i'm in... Don't you think? STI seems to not resolve that database issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `composed_of`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html

create `(Common)Deadline` class,

```
class Deadline
    attr_reader :date, :status

    def initialize(date, status)
      @date, @status = date, status
    end

    # write common method
end

class GeneralDeadline < Deadline
  attr_read :received_status

  def initialize(date, status, received_status)
    super(date, status)
    @received_status = received_status
  end
end

class FinancialDeadline < Deadline
  def initialize(date, status, received_status)
    super(date, status)
    @amount = amount
  end

  # define method!
end
```

and define association with `composed_of`

```
class GeneralContract
  composed_of :deadline, class_name: 'GeneralDeadline', mapping: [%w(received_status received_status), %w(date date), %w(status status)]
end

class FinancialContract
  composed_of :deadline, class_name: 'FinancialDeadline', mapping: [%w(amount amount), %w(date date), %w(status status)]
end
```

Comment: I'm going to study this. Many thanks :)